# Create new field based on data from spreadsheet?

Tags: formula, excel

I'd like to create a new field for Account objects in Salesforce which is filled based on if the Account Name matches one of the names on a spreadsheet that I have. So I basically want to have a giant if statement that says if the account name = any of the entries on the spreadsheet, make the field say "...". Is there any way to easily do this? Thanks!

Comment: Would you consider re-wording your question? It doesn't make much sense to me. I'm not clear if your question is about a spreadsheet formula or something specific to Salesforce.

Comment: Sorry... I'm talking about a field in Salesforce for Account objects.

Comment: I'm also confused. At first you say you want to add a new field, but then it sounds like you just want to change a field's value. These are very different actions; can you clarify?

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful if you could edit your question and provide a very explicit example of some of the data which would be in the spreadsheet and then an example of what you would like to see in a field when that specific data is loaded. It would also be good to know how you intend to load this data into the org.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a formula field on the Account that displays some kind of additional information based on the Name field on the Account. There is no way to directly use a spreadsheet to determine this value. However, he `CASE()` formula might do the trick:

```
CASE(
    Name, 
    "abc", "The ABC Company",  
    "def", "The DEF Company", 
    "Unknown"
    )
```

So now you can create an Account, enter "abc" in the Name field, and your formula field will display "The ABC Company". If the Name value isn't in the list, it will say "Unknown".

Note that there is a character limit on formulas, so this strategy will only work for a few Account Names, especially if you need to populate a lot of text. This formula field will also have to be edited whenever you add more Account Names to your list.

If what you're looking for is more complicated than this solution, you may need to think about a custom object or custom setting to store your Account Name mapping, and you could use an Apex Trigger to populate your new field based on querying that table.

Comment: Yeah, I considered this but unfortunately with the amount of data I have, it goes way past the character limit. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is keeping your information in a custom object as a lookup table an option?

Answer (score 0):

Create an account report with name and account I'd columns

Export the report to excel and match your accounts with the values you want on your existing spreadsheet

Import back to salesforce and make sure you as that field with the conditional values you wanted.

The alternative is to create an apex trigger on the account that fires every time you update a  specific field like account name. In the trigger you could have a list of values to match against and update your custom field on the account. Use a list of type map maybe.